# How to use an init(from decoder:) when reading bundled JSON data

Tags: json, swift, init, decoder

I have have a JSON dictionary array and need to decode it to make a data type (Hitter), the Hitter object needs to hold the raw JSON data and I need to add properties to the Hitter throughout the life of the app. I've discovered I need to use init(from decoder:) but how do I call the init properly...I will be storing the Hitter in the League struct.

```
struct League {
    var Hitters: Set<Hitter>

    func loadHitters() {
        ...//ingest json from bundle, 
           //store decoded Hitter objects in temp array, 
           //then append each item from temp array into League.Hitters set.
    }
}
```

To be clear, my Hitter struct already has the init set up, I need help using the decoder from this point.

EDIT:
I've discovered the solution and it requires the use of retrieving the JSON keys and linking them to your CodingKeys enum. Here's my shortened Hitter class:

```
struct Hitter: Player, Decodable {
    //partial list of properties in JSON data
    let strPos: String
    let OBP: Float
    let wRAA: Float //weightedRunsAboveAverage
    //partial list of properties in JSON data - end
    //partial list of additional properties
    var valAboveReplacement: Float = 0.0
    var wOBP: Float {
        return OBP * Float(PA)
    }
    //partial list of additional properties - end
}
```

I declare the CodingKeys and init(decoder:) in an extension for compartmentalization's sake

```
extension Hitter {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case strPos, OBP, wRAA
    }

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        //container links all the CodingKeys and JSONDecoder keys for proper referencing. Returns the data stored in this decoder as represented in a container keyed by the given key type
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let strPos = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .strPos)
        let OBP = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .OBP)
        let wRAA = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .wRAA)

        //pass my decoded values via a standard initializer
        self.init(strPos: strPos, OBP: OBP, wRAA: wRAA)
    }

}
```

This seems to work perfectly fine so long as I explicitly link the JSON format and the CodingKeys via a container.

Comment: If you decode it using JSONDecoder the init will be used automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you design  a struct, you get an memberwise `initializer` for free — assuming you don't define others `initializers` yourself But `Struct` auto inititializers are internal. You have to generate memeberwise `initializer` when you writing a `module` to make it public

> "Default Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types The default
>   memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered private if
>   any of the structure’s stored properties are private. Otherwise, the
>   initializer has an access level of internal.
>
> As with the default initializer above, if you want a public structure
>   type to be initializable with a memberwise initializer when used in
>   another module, you must provide a public memberwise initializer
>   yourself as part of the type’s definition."

Swift Docs "[Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)"